# How to get records from Quickbase in asp.net application?

Tags: c#, quickbase

```
IQClient client = Intuit.QuickBase.Client.QuickBase.Login("username", "pwd");
IQApplication app = client.Connect(applicationId, token);
Intuit.QuickBase.Client.IQTable rtable = app.GetTable(sTableID);`
```

I am creating a web application in asp.net. I need to get data from quickbase to populate my GridView. I am using Quickbase API.The above code retrieves the table, but records value is always 0. Am I doing anything wrong or Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all of the records in the table you can follow the example at the following site:
https://code.intuit.com/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.quickbase_c_sdk/wiki/HomePage .

```
using System;
using Intuit.QuickBase.Client;

namespace MyProgram.QB.Interaction
{
    class MyApplication
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = QuickBase.Client.QuickBase.Login("your_QB_username", "your_QB_password");
            var application = client.Connect("your_app_dbid", "your_app_token");
            var table = application.GetTable("your_table_dbid");
            table.Query();

            foreach(var record in table.Records)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(record["your_column_heading"]);
            }
            client.Logout();
        }
    }
}
```

To do specific query using the already built C# API, you can do the following:

```
var querystring1 = new QueryStrings(FieldID,ComparisonOperator.GTE,value,LogicalOperator.AND);
var querystring2 = new QueryStrings(FieldID, ComparisonOperator.XEX, value, LogicalOperator.NONE);
```

then

```
    var query = new Query();
query.Add(querystring1);
query.Add(querystring2);
table.Query(query, new[] { 1,2,3,4}, new[] { 1,2});
```

The second parameter is the field IDs of the columns you want and the Third parameter is the field ID's to sort the records by.

In your case I would just do the loop and add all the records to a collection. Then you could probably use LINQ or just the column headings to loop through all your records.

This is the way I did it to get specific data:

```
foreach(var record in table.Records)
            {
                var row = new String[8];
                row[0] = record["Column Name"];
                row[1] = record["Column Name"];
                row[2] = record["Column Name"];
                row[3] = record["Column Name"];
                row[4] = record["Column Name"];
                row[5] = record["Column Name"];
                row[6] = record["Column Name"];
                row[7] = record["Column Name"];
                list.Add(row);//This is a List<string[]> collection. But use what you want
            }
```